# Is there a list of all the classes or classnames used in all the components in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

We would like to work over the complete CSS of material-ui. For that, we are gonna use the [Global theme override](https://material-ui.com/es/customization/components/#global-theme-override) option.

For that, we need all the CSS classes used in all the components.

As you can see in the docs from material-ui, the classnames are splitted between the Component API for each component. That means that if I want to extact them all, I should browse all the Components API

Is described in any place? Or should I make my own?

Comment: unfortunately there is no such thing as a list of all material ui classes, you should look every class up at "api" page of that particular component

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks pedram6195
I decide to crawl the documentation of material-ui, and extract the classnames.
I used cypress to do it and it took maybe an hour.

```js
const classes = new Map();

describe('Get classnames', () => {
  after(() => {
    cy.writeFile('classes.json', Array.from(classes));
  });
  it('should load the main page', () => {
    apis.map(api => {
      const currentClasses = [];
      cy.visit(api);
      cy.get('table')
        .get('span.prop-name')
        .each(($el) => {
          if ($el.text().startsWith('.Mui')) { currentClasses.push($el.text()); };
          classes.set(api, currentClasses);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

where `apis` are an array with the link from the Componetn API section from [material-ui.com](http://material-ui.com)

To make it more faster, material-ui alllows to run the documentation in a local server.